# Get Location (Latitude and Longitude)

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude

I am new at android. I wrote a code. And my purpose is when I get an SMS send my location to incoming SMS number.

I can get and send SMS, but I cant send my location (as latitude and longitude). How can I do that. Believe me, I have no idea how i do that. I wrote some code in onlocationChange() method. But it doesnt give me location.

Please give me an advice.

Thanks for your help.

Here my code :

```
package com.example.smsmessaging; 

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

@SuppressLint("UnlocalizedSms")
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener
{
    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })  
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
        SmsMessage[] mesaj = null;  
        String str = "";  
        String sender = ""; 
        if (bundle != null) 
        {           

            Object[] obj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            mesaj = new SmsMessage[obj.length]; 

            for (int i=0; i<mesaj.length; i++){ 
                mesaj[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])obj[i]);                 
                sender = mesaj[i].getOriginatingAddress();                    
                str += mesaj[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            }

            Toast.makeText(context,"SMS," + sender + " tarafından gönderildi\n\nSMS in içeriği : " + 
            str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
            String mIMEINumber = tMgr.getDeviceId();
            Toast.makeText(context,"My Phone no : " + mPhoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context,"My IMEI no : " + mIMEINumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(sender.toString(), null, str, null, null); 

            Toast.makeText(context,"SMS sent ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

        }                         
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = Integer.parseInt(location.getLatitude()+" ");
        int lon = Integer.parseInt(location.getLongitude()+" ");

        String efe = "Location  " + " Longitude : " + lon  + "\n Latitude : "  + lat;
        Context context = null;

        try {
              SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
              sms.sendTextMessage("1555215554", null, efe, null, null);

              Toast.makeText(context,"location sent. Details : " + efe, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    
        } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: are u getting lattitude and longitude on locationchanged?

Comment: Yes I can , but I want to when I get an SMS then send my current location.

Comment: Did you add permissions?

Comment: yes i did all permission

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: I feel there is some problem in these lines. 
int lat = Integer.parseInt(location.getLatitude()+" ");
int lon = Integer.parseInt(location.getLongitude()+" ");
Did you try replacing that with code I mentioned in answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found a solution. and my edited code is like below:

```
package com.example.donemprojesi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.location.*;
import android.content.*;

public class AnaActivity extends Activity {
    Location currentLocation;
    public static double currentLatitude=0.0;
    public static double currentLongitude=0.0;  
    public static String currentAddress=" ";
    public static String str = "efe";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ana);
        finish();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    updateLocation(location);
                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

                    if("efe".equals(str) && SmsReceiver.flag == true){
                        try{
                            sms.sendTextMessage(SmsReceiver.sender.toString(), null,"Koordinatlar : Enlem = " +currentLatitude + 
                                    ", Boylam = " +currentLongitude, null, null);

                            sms.sendTextMessage(SmsReceiver.sender.toString(), null,"Adres : " + currentAddress + 
                                    " Haritadaki Konum : " + "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + currentLatitude + 
                                    "," + currentLongitude, null, null);
                        }catch(Exception ex){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mesaj gönderiminde bir hata ile karşılaşıldı...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            sms.sendTextMessage(SmsReceiver.sender.toString(), null,"Konum gönderiminde bir hata ile karşılaşıldı...", null, null);
                        }
                        finally{
                            SmsReceiver.flag =false;
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }
                public void onStatusChanged(
                        String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {/*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/}
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {/*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/}
            };

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            bildirim();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_ana, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void bildirim(){

        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view;
        CharSequence ticketText = "GPSMS Started";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, ticketText, when);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "GPSMS";
        CharSequence contentText = "GPSMS Enabled";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AnaActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        mNotificationManager.notify(BIND_AUTO_CREATE, notification);    
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        try{
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude,100);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                    Address address =  (Address) addresses.get(0);
                    int maxIndex = address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();
                    for (int x = 0; x <= maxIndex; x++ ){
                        if(address.getAddressLine(x) != null){
                            result.append(address.getAddressLine(x)).append("\n");
                        }
                    }               
                    if(address.getLocality() !=null){
                        result.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                    }
                    if(address.getPostalCode() !=null){
                        result.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                    }

                    if(address.getCountryName() !=null){
                        result.append(address.getCountryName()).append("\n");
                    }
                return result.toString();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            return ex.getMessage().toString();
        }
        return "Location not found";
    }

    void updateLocation(Location location){
        currentLocation = location;
        currentLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
        currentAddress = getAddress();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I edited out the link to http://sdrv.ms/WCBFRj, because it seems to be inaccessible.  If you have an newer link, please consider an [edit] to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myLocation = "My current location is: " + "Latitude = "
                + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();
```

This code had worked for me.